# In Python create a file containing a table showing the 1st 1000 prime numbers and print so that there are 10 primes per row, 100 rows

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am unsure how to create the rows and columns as well as to print it to a separate file. 
This is what I have so far.

```
for num in range(2,1001):
    if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):      
        print (num)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('solution.txt', 'w') as f:
    n = 0
    for num in range(2,1001):
        if all(num%i != 0 for i in range(2, num)):
            if n == 10:
                f.write('%s\n' % num) # Start a new line
                n = 0
            else:
                f.write('%s ' % num) # Don't start a new line
            n += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to print the result in a way to where the numbers are neatly in the columns?